# Finding road segements which are not split at intersection.(Query Optimization )

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgis, query-performance

I have a query in which I am trying to find the road segments which intersect but are not splitted at intersection,I have also created gist index on geom column. Here is postgerSQL srcipt

```
SELECT a.id touched, b.id touching,  ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)
FROM   pak_roads a, pak_roads b
WHERE ST_Crosses(a.geom, b.geom) and a.id < b.id and (a.MODE IS NULL
and b.MODE IS NULL )
and (a.grade_t IS NULL and a.grade_f IS NULL)
and (b.grade_t IS NULL and b.grade_f IS NULL) OR
-- "vertical" T bar, touching
(
 -- The "vertical" start node touches, but not on either of the "horizonal" nodes
 ST_Equals(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom), ST_StartPoint(b.geom))
 AND NOT ST_Equals(ST_StartPoint(a.geom), ST_StartPoint(b.geom))
 AND NOT ST_Equals(ST_EndPoint(a.geom), ST_StartPoint(b.geom))
 ) OR (
 -- The "vertical" end node touches, but not on either of the "horizonal" nodes
 ST_Equals(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom), ST_EndPoint(b.geom))
 AND NOT ST_Equals(ST_StartPoint(a.geom), ST_EndPoint(b.geom))
 AND NOT ST_Equals(ST_EndPoint(a.geom), ST_EndPoint(b.geom))
 )
```

Logic is working fine but it takes a lot of time to complete this task, can someone let me know how can I optimize this query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom) at the start of second and third queries, as st_intersects is fast so it only calculates st_intersection where st_intersects returns 'True' hence performance of query is enhanced. Below is the query after modification.

```
SELECT a.id touched, b.id touching,  ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom)
FROM   pak_roads a, pak_roads b
WHERE ST_Crosses(a.geom, b.geom) and a.id < b.id and (a.MODE IS NULL
and b.MODE IS NULL )
and (a.grade_t IS NULL and a.grade_f IS NULL)
and (b.grade_t IS NULL and b.grade_f IS NULL) OR
-- "vertical" T bar, touching
(
-- The "vertical" start node touches, but not on either of the "horizonal" --nodes
st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom) and ST_Equals(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom), 
ST_StartPoint(b.geom))
AND NOT ST_Equals(ST_StartPoint(a.geom), ST_StartPoint(b.geom))
AND NOT ST_Equals(ST_EndPoint(a.geom), ST_StartPoint(b.geom))
) OR (
-- The "vertical" end node touches, but not on either of the "horizonal" 
--nodes
st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom) and ST_Equals(ST_Intersection(a.geom, b.geom), ST_EndPoint(b.geom))
AND NOT ST_Equals(ST_StartPoint(a.geom), ST_EndPoint(b.geom))
AND NOT ST_Equals(ST_EndPoint(a.geom), ST_EndPoint(b.geom))
)
```

But I think there is still some room for improvement.